# How find nested Redux containers in a shallow render?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I'm testing nested Redux containers with Jest and Enzyme.

If a child nested component class is called MyComponent and I shallow render them with Enzyme, they show in a snapshot as:

```
<Connect(MyComponent) myProp='someValue' />
```

Is there a way to find these containers with Enzyme? The following fail:

```
expect(wrapper.find(MyComponent)).toHaveLength(1);
expect(wrapper.find('MyComponent')).toHaveLength(1);
expect(wrapper.find('Connect(MyComponent)')).toHaveLength(1);
```

I know I can use `mount` instead and test for e.g. class names, but I thought it would make sense to keep the rendering shallow for simplicity and speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Enzyme's [`.dive()` function](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html):

```
expect(wrapper.dive().find("MyComponent").exists()).toBe(true)
```